# Using variable in .aspx in vs 2012 is giving error Type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlElement' is not defined

Tags: visual-studio, .net-4.5

I have the following .aspx code

```
<table style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt; LINE-HEIGHT: 115%; FONT-FAMILY: tahoma">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2"><%#readfile("header")%><br>
                            <br>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
```

I am getting

> Type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlElement' is not defined.

on <%#readfile("header")%> row.

```
Public Function readfile(ByVal filename)
    Dim objstreamReader As StreamReader
    Dim strHtml As String
    Dim  phypath =  filename & ".htm"
    If File.Exists(phypath) Then
        objstreamReader = File.OpenText(phypath)
        strHtml = objstreamReader.ReadToEnd
        objstreamReader.Close()
    End If
    readfile = strHtml
End Function
```

This code used to run and build successfully in visual studio 2010. But now in visual studio 2012 it is giving error. How can i fix that? Even if i replace the function code in vb to something simple like returning a temp string i am still getting the error from .aspx page.

Answer (score 0):

Are all your assembly references in place?

Comment: do u mean  <assemblies> under configuration in web.config?

Comment: Nope. In the project explorer window your project should have a folder named References. Check in there.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a new Asp.Net VB web forms application and added your markup and code to the default page. Even though there are some minor issues I could not reproduce the error you are getting.

I do suggest though that you assign a default value to strHtml and change <%#readfile("header")%> to <%:readfile("header")%> as a start.

another thing to consider is where exactly you content files (the htm files you are feeding to that function) are located. Currently it's a bit ambiguous which will cause problems later on.